# If we are not doing a subscription service, should we store the Stripe token id

Tags: stripe-payments

This is my first time using Stripe and I just set up a service where people will be buying things one-off. I was handed a partially completed implementation where we stored the user token id but I'm thinking this is unnecessary and probably not such a good idea.

Would there be any reason for us to store their Stripe token id? Would storing it represent a security concern? If somebody was able to access our code and our database, would they be able to do a transaction under that username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be quite useful to store the charge id (ch_ id) and some info about the charge (amount, last 4 of the card, etc) so that you don't need to call out to Stripe's API each time you need that information. Since tokens (tok_ id) can only be used once and are only guaranteed for 5 minutes, there is no purpose in storing them.

There are also customer ids (cus_ id) but if you're only doing one off charges, the need to create a customer is debatable.

Comment: thx - even though one off, I am currently doing a customer_id. let me look into this more later today; running into meeting.

Comment: Is storing the "last four of the card" permitted by the card companies? I thought that would be a violation so serious that a trader could lose their right to handle card numbers.